# How butterknife inject actionbar custom view?

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using [ButterKnife](https://github.com/butterknife) in my project and it's awesome.

I can inject the content view in my Activity by ButterKnife.inject(this), I'm also using custom view in my actionbar:

```
private void configActionbar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    View actionbarView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionbarView);
}
```

I want to bind onclick listener on the view included in the actionbar.
The tradition way like following:

```
Button a = (Button)actionbarView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
a.setOnClickListener(xxxx) ;
```

Expected ButterKnife way:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void btnClick(){....}
```

How to use ButterKnife way in my case?

Answer (score 9):

Seems you misunderstood core ButterKnife mechanics. In general case, all the ids you use in annotations are ids of activity/fragment **view of class** you working with.

`LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null)` gives you another one `View` which views ButterKnife can't reach.

The best thing ButterKnife may do for you in this case is convenient `findById` methods. Have a look at this code:

```
private void configActionbar() {
    ...

    View actionbarView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionbarView);

    // Yep, this is best ButterKnife can do for you
    Button button = ButterKnife.findById(actionbarView, R.id.btn);
    // And then old fashion Android code...
    button.setOnClickListener(...);
}
```

**Edit:**

Oh, I have an idea.
Let's try next code:

```
View actionbarView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        .inflate(R.layout.actionbar_view, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionbarView);

ButterKnife.inject(actionBar, actionbarView); // actionBar as argument is for keep track of injection. Read about memleak below.
```

But keep in mind, in this case you may have some conflicts, because ButterKnife will try to inject every annotated field/method twice (for a activity/fragment layout and then for a actionbarView). So i don't recommend you use this solution. But if you like it, have a look at ButterKnife `@Optional` annotation, it may save you from exceptions that ButterKnife throws in case of conflicts.

And I am not sure about memleaks in this case (approach is like inject for fragments). So, most likely you should manually call `ButterKnife.release(actionbarView)` in right moment (I can't exactly say when, perhaps inside `onDestroyView()`).

*Under ButterKnife conflicts I mean situation when ButterKnife can't find views for annotated fields/methods or several injected views contains child views with duplicated ids*

Comment: Injecting into ActionBar doesn't work :-) only the findById option worked for me